# Можно ли сделать так чтобы при сборке yarn run build небыло 404

Tags: build, yarn

Я запускаю команду (install-assets) сборки из Makefile.
В этой команде выполняется:

```
    docker-compose run --rm my-node-cli yarn install
    docker-compose run --rm my-node-cli npm rebuild node-sass
    docker-compose run --rm my-node-cli yarn run build
```

В время yarn run build сайт выдаёт 404, можно ли как-то сделать так чтобы оно там в фоне тихонько пересобралось но при этом сайт не выдавал 404, а работал на старой сборке, пока не собралась новая и после сборки новые файлы заменили бы старые?

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось всё просто, нужно добавить опцию --no-clean (не удалять "dist/" перед сборкой)